# Strong closure of nilpotent algebra

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras

Let $A\subset \mathcal K(H)$ be a commutative algebra of compact operators on a separable Hilbert space $H$. Let $B\supset A$ be the closure of $A$ in the strong operator topology.
Assume that each $T\in A$ is quasi-nilpotent, i.e. we have $\sigma(T)=\{0\}$.
Can it happen that $B$ contains the identity?

In other words, can there be a sequence $(T_j)$ of compact operators with $\lim_n\parallel T_j^n\parallel^{1/n}=0$ such that $T_iT_j=T_jT_i$ for all $i,j\in\mathbb N$ and $\parallel T_jv-v\parallel\to 0$ as $j\to\infty$ for every $v\in H$?

Comment: I have a vague memory of answering something similar before... in any case, the answer is yes. Take the Volterra operator acting on $L^2[0,1]$ and let $A$ be the algebra it generates: this algebra has a bounded approximate identity, so the SOT closure will include the identity operator

Comment: Found it - and it was one of your questions https://mathoverflow.net/questions/111645/strongly-convergent-operator-sequence/111677

Comment: Incidentally, your title says nilpotent but your question seems to only require quasinilpotent...

Comment: Wow, I entirely forgot. I'll have my brain checked...

Comment: @Yemon Choi: if you make this comment an answer, I can give the bounty.